# CI/CD Pipeline for a dot net core application with 2 DLL files stored in the folder in Azure DevOps Repository - issues with build and release

Tags: dll, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

My team is doing the implementation of a dot net core application to a customer. For this implementation, we use a highly configurable dot net core platform, where we override some capabilities at the implementation level. The core platform is protected (we have 2 DLL files)which we need in order to have a successful build/ release in visual studio. On the local machine, it builds properly, but when we try to configure the build/ release pipeline on Azure DevOps, "An error occurred while starting the application.
DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\home\site\MyApplication\wwwroot".

I have source code in the repo on Azure DevOps, and these two dll files are there as well. I know it would be much easier if we have packages (NuGet) instead of dll files, but we don't have them. We only have dll files.

I guess I am missing to make them available properly for my build task and that's why we don't build application properly.

Is there anyone to share either YAML file or classic deployment instructions, how to do this properly?

This is the YAML I have, which doesn't work:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'CoreAppFolder'
    Contents: '**/.dll'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Comment: Nothing you've posted would result in the error you're reporting. Please provide what you're doing that causes the error you're troubleshooting.

Comment: How did you reference the dlls locally? Could you share the detailed log?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my build passed, release passed as well. But, when I click on the URL to view my site, I see this error. I assume that build hasn't been done properly. Maybe I am wrong as well.
[image]

Comment: Please add comment or edit your original post for updated information, instead of adding a reply. I'd like to confirm with you when you build and release your project locally, how's the result? How did you reference the dlls locally?

Answer (score 0):

> CI/CD Pipeline for a dot net core application with 2 DLL files stored in the folder in Azure DevOps Repository - issues with build and release

That because you are using the `DotNetCoreCLI build` task instead of `publish` task.

The default work folder for the `DotNetCoreCLI build` is `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`. But the default path to publish of the task `PublishBuildArtifacts` is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

So, the artifact file only include those two dll files.

To resolve this issue, try to use `DotNetCoreCLI publish` task instead of build task:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```